# violated - parent key not found when using generated SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I used a plugin in Intellij to generate SQL and it looks correct but I keep getting an error saying `violated - parent key not found`

*Added for clarity: 'LOCAL.fOO_LANGUAGE_FK) violated - parent key not found'*

To make it I used this:

```
create table fOO
(
  Foo_ID                NUMBER                      not null
    constraint CAMPAIGN_PK
    primary key,
```

Comment: problem #1 - insert into system. --> you should NOT be adding objects to SYS or SYSTEM. create a local schema, log in as that user, and add your objects there

Comment: problem #2 - your table has REFERENCES to 5 other tables. Your insert is using a value in a column tied to one of those tables that is not present. For example your INSERTing 1 for SHOP_ID, but there is no record 1 in the SHOP table.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith thank you for thanking the time to post. I created a new scheme and added data to the `SHOP` table but got the same error `LOCAL.SHOP_LANGUAGE_FK) violated - parent key not found`

Comment: you have 4 other references to other tables, make sure your LAYOUT, SEVERITY, CAMPAIGN_USAGE, and SALE_QUALIFICATION tables have their associated values as well.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I cannot even add data to language and that is the parent to shop. I attached the diagram, I am trying over here.

Comment: So you can't add data to shop, because you can't add data to language. So, if you absolutely MUST insert this record, you can disable the FK constraint Campaign_Shop_Fk -- if you do this, you're going to have orphaned records, and you're going to let MORE bad data in AND make it impossible to re-enable that constraint if you don't fix the data in the parent table(s)

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I need to render data and to do that I need to insert. I do no care if I have to initialize the whole DB locally. I would actually really like that but right now I just have 183 generated SQL files and I have not gotten them to work

Comment: disable all of your foreign keys, insert all the data, and if you do it right, you can then re-establish the constraints

Comment: also, next time you report an error on SO, report the ACTUAL ERROR: 'LOCAL.SHOP_LANGUAGE_FK) violated - parent key not found' - that tells us and you exactly what the problem is, otherwise we get to guess

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169025/discussion-between-drew1208-and-thatjeffsmith).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to insert a record into a table which references 5 other tables:

1. SHOP
2. SEVERITY
3. CAMPAIGN_USAGE
4. LAYOUT
5. SALE_QUALIFICATION

These references are enforced by constraints. These constraints are rules that the database enforces on your data, and it's based on your data model.

By comments shared in your follow-up, you also have a LANGUAGE table references by your SHOP table.

So to insert a record into your table, you have to make sure the referenced values are all present in your other 5 or more tables.

If you cannot insert the data in the correct order, it's quite common when building out your schema, to create the foreign key constraints DISABLED, INSERT all the data, COMMIT, and then ENABLE all the constraints back on.

To disable a constraint, for example 'CAMPAIGN_SHOP_FK', you can

```
alter table CAMPAIGN disable constraint CAMPAIGN_SHOP_FK;
```

It is VITAL that you enable your constraints back if you do not want orphaned rows in your data model.

Some folks will mistakenly rely on their software to ensure their data is 'clean'. If you do this, then you are betting your software is error free AND that no one is in the database touching your data. Both cases are rarely, if ever, true.